# Swift dynamic segues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, swift2

This might be a dumb question but I am new to Swift. So, I wanted to create an app which will have a menu with a few chapters and individual chapters will have 2 segues of course chapters followed by a quiz at the end of each chapter. Was wondering what will be the best practice to programmatically set it up in Swift following the MVC pattern. I am not really sure how to call a module of segues via a TableViewCell on the menu.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't do stuff like this (check the image below) you will be fine.

[image: HOW NOT TO DO SEGUES]

Comment: Can you explain why is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: I would need to do something like that. I want the user to have the ability to  go back to the previous screen and all segues should also have a menu button which would take them to the main menu.

Comment: you can use navigation controller to perform these kind of loops, you don't wan't to have stacked view controllers on top of each other, you need to dismiss them when you don't need them anymore.

you can go to the root menu for example with a method like this:

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have four (1..4) chapters that accessible through menu (represented as `UITableView`). Each chapter can rely to quiz controller. It will look like this:

[image]

About cell: you can call `performSegue("id", sender: sender)` inside `UITableViewDelegate`'s method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Or you can command-drag segue from your cell to controller. But all cells will call the same segue.

**Update.** If you need your menu to be visible in all controllers (e.g. side left/right menu) look at [this](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) library.